# How to make migrate Django with Docker

Tags: django, docker

I have docker `db` and `web` containers. After command `docker-compose up -d --build` I have errors with not exists relations in DB. I really don't have tables in DB. I execute following command:

```
$ docker-compose exec web python manage.py migrate
```

And I have following output:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, autos, bot, contenttypes, sessions, sites
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  ...
```

If I execute this command second time, then I get `No migrations to apply.`, but I still don't have tables in DB.

Part of my `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: '3.3'

x-base: &base
  restart: unless-stopped
  build: .
  working_dir: /code/autotracker
  env_file:
    - .env

services:
  web:
    <<: *base
    command: gunicorn autotracker.wsgi -b :8001
    volumes:
      - "/static:/static"
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - .env.db
    ports:
      - 5432

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Comment: How is the database configured in your application?  Is it using something like a local SQLite, instead of the PostgreSQL container?

Comment: It looks like postgreSQL from the docker-compose file... however, @dzianis-talkachou what are your DATABASES settings in your settings.py? Can you easily run migrations manually, locally and have the app work as intended?

Comment: Yes. I did have invalid settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try make migrate first. by :

```
docker-compose exec web python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

after that try migrate :

```
docker-compose exec web python manage.py migrate
```

and then after finish two top command try :

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

Comment: I have all migrations. After first executing `migrate` I have output.

Comment: nice job. good luck